# Nested event loop with with Rust - avoiding borrowing conflicts

Tags: rust

I'm implementing user interface with event loop with objects that contain other objects and dispatch messages, it looks something like this:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
struct Bitmap {}

enum Event {
    KeyDown(char),
    //MousdeDown(u32, u32)
}

trait Gadget {
    fn paint(&mut self) -> Bitmap;
    fn handle_event(&mut self, event: Event, owner : &mut Widget);
}

struct Widget {
    gadgets: Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Gadget>>>,
    active_gadget: usize,
}

fn get_event() -> Event { return Event::KeyDown('x'); }

impl Widget {
    pub fn event_loop(&mut self) {
        loop {
            {
                let event = get_event();
                self.gadgets[self.active_gadget]
                    .clone()
                    .borrow_mut()
                    .handle_event(event, self);
            }
            // if need_repaint
            {
                for i in 0..self.gadgets.len() {
                    let _ = self.gadgets[i].clone().borrow_mut().paint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    pub fn modal(&mut self) {
        // save some state, add another gadget, make it active
        self.event_loop();
    }
}
```

The event handler can modify the state of the Gadget so needs to be borrowed mutable.  The event handler could create a modal dialog which calls for a nested event loop but that panics on repaint because the nested event loop cannot borrow the first Gadget a second time.

How can I restructure this to comply with Rust's borrow rules?

Comment: Hi John, your example seems to run fine in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b6485ed3bf95af008d74f1a2af74850). Maybe you can add some code to this that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Issue happens when calling the function `modal` as in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eaf335deabb9692dadebcef5580c4188)

Comment: What's happening is in `event_loop()`, `<gadget>.borrow_mut().handle_event()` keeps a gadget borrow on the stack as `.handle_event()` is called, then `handle_event()` indirectly invokes `event_loop()` again (recursion), which calls `<gadget>.borrow_mut()...` again on the same gadget.

Comment: I applied a pattern I've used before to your code to fix the problem with held references on the stack. If you decide you want to use it, you'll have a lot less trouble with borrowing conflicts as your code grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick Fix

A quick fix for the problem which, depending on your implementation, may or may not work is to use `.try_borrow_mut()` anywhere that it's possible another stack frame is still holding a reference to the same object.

```rust
                for i in 0..self.gadgets.len() {
                    if let Ok(mut gadget_ref) = self.gadgets[i]
                                                    .clone()
                                                    .try_borrow_mut() {
                        let _ = gadget_ref.paint();
                    }
                }
```

This gets rid of the borrowing conflict - all the gadgets but one will be painted. I'm not sure what the consequences of that will be in your implementation. My other approach below allows all the gadgets to have their paint methods called on them despite the state of other stack frames.

#### Ideas for redesign

Perhaps your application could be restructured to use a task queue where tasks are submitted and then executed, and the results are handed off to a callback also supplied with the task. This could remove the need to nest the event loop. Taking another approach should be easy if the actual project is still in its early stages.

#### Dynamic runtime borrowing challenges

With on-demand borrowing at runtime using smart pointers we need to be careful to avoid situations where code could potentially become deadlocked or panic when a mutable borrow is requested to an object that is already borrowed elsewhere.

Using the fallible borrow methods, like `try_borrow_mut()` is one way to deal with the problem. Using that we'd also have to take care that we don't write code where acquiring needed references fail too often.

With *immutable* borrows, borrowing conflicts are much less problematic, we can request any number of immutable borrows we want. So an approach that reduces or eliminates the potential for *mutable* borrows can be of benefit.

Method signatures with mutable references to `self` require client code to acquire a mutable reference to the object before invoking them. Since there can only be one mutable borrow at a time, method signatures that take an immutable reference are more flexible.

An approach that I found to address complicated on-demand borrowing requirements of code involves doing two things:

- Reduce or eliminate mutable `self` references on methods.
- Put all, or pieces of, the internal state of objects behind smart pointers.

The second task above helps achieve the first task. I'm sure I'm not the first to think of the following approach. It seems almost intuitive for anyone coming from C++ to consider. The idiom/pattern I'm talking about is the C++ pImpl pattern.

#### Mutable pImpl pattern for Rust

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=964e9e36e35d07e46f087c40b0b7c475)

This pattern that can alleviate borrow checker hell, is similar to the old C++ pimpl pattern for classes where the state of the class is behind a pointer, and the methods of the external class use its private pointer to access and mutate its state.

In the same way we can separate the state of a class/struct from the struct itself. Below I separated the public `Widget`'s internal state out into a private struct, `WidgetState`, and added a field to `Widget` for the new internal state.

```rust
struct WidgetState {
    gadgets: Vec<Rc<dyn Gadget>>,
    active_gadget: usize,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Widget {
    internal_state: Rc<RefCell<WidgetState>>,
}
```

With this pattern, we can pass around immutable references as parameters to methods everywhere and anywhere, and invoke the more flexible methods that don't require mutable `self`, and if the implementation in a method requires mutability, it uses `.borrow_mut()` internally.

The next step I did was make all the methods take non mutable references to `self`. Since we can get a mutable reference on demand inside any of `Widget`'s methods now, `.event_loop()` no longer needs a mutable `self` reference:

```rust
    pub fn event_loop(&self) {
        for _ in 0..2 {
            {
                let event = get_event();
                let i_active = self.state().active_gadget;
                let active = self.state().gadgets[i_active].clone();
                active.handle_event(event, self);
            }
            // if need_repaint
            {
                let state = self.state();
                for i in 0..state.gadgets.len() {
                    let _ = state.gadgets[i].paint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fn state(&self) -> Ref<WidgetState> {
        self.internal_state.borrow()
    }
    fn state_mut(&self) -> RefMut<WidgetState> {
        self.internal_state.borrow_mut()
    }
```

When using the references returned by `.state()` or `.state_mut()` above, sometimes we can assign state to a local variable so we don't have to keep invoking those methods for every access to state. But in cases where we need fine grained borrowing, we can scope the returned references appropriately.

For instance, to redo `.modal()`, I had to ensure there were no held references to the `Widget`'s internal state before invoking `event_loop()` (recursively).. I added a scope before that call so the reference to state would be dropped early.

```rust
    pub fn modal(&self) {
        let save_active;
        {
            let mut state = self.state_mut();
            save_active = state.active_gadget;
            let idx_gadgets = state.gadgets.len() - 1;
            state.active_gadget = idx_gadgets;
        }
        self.add_gadget(Rc::new(YGadget::new()));
        self.event_loop();
        let mut state = self.state_mut();
        state.active_gadget = save_active;
        state.gadgets.pop();
    }
```

I reworked each struct and their methods to use this pattern, and got it running without any major redesign.

I could probably have gotten away with applying this pattern only to `Gadget` - that was the base trait for the object that was causing the panic. But for this example, I applied the pattern to `Widget` as well because it was easy to make these changes, and could ensure it also benefits from more flexibility.

Whether you want to follow this pattern and put the entire state of your structs behind smart pointers or not is up to you. You could structure your classes differently, but keep the idea that you can reduce borrowing conflicts by isolating out parts of the internal state of objects and relaxing the mutable reference requirements of your methods.

Full code of the example below:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Bitmap {}

enum Event {
    KeyDown(char),
    //MousdeDown(u32, u32)
}

trait Gadget {
    fn paint(&self) -> Bitmap;
    fn handle_event(&self, event: Event, owner : &Widget);
}

struct XGadget { }
impl Gadget for XGadget {
    fn handle_event(&self, event: Event, owner: &Widget) {
        println!("popping message box");
        owner.modal();
    }
    fn paint(&self) -> Bitmap {
        println!("painting...");
        Bitmap { }
    }
}


struct YGadget { 
    state: Rc<RefCell<String>>,
}
// ###
impl YGadget {
    fn new() -> Self {
        YGadget { 
            state: Rc::new(RefCell::new("Internal State".into())),
        }
    }
}
impl Gadget for YGadget {
    fn handle_event(&self, event: Event, owner: &Widget) {
    }
    fn paint(&self) -> Bitmap {
        println!("Ypainting...");
        println!("Updating state...");
        // ###
        self.state.borrow_mut().push_str(": UPDATED!");
        Bitmap { }
    }
}
struct WidgetState {
    gadgets: Vec<Rc<dyn Gadget>>,
    active_gadget: usize,
}

struct Widget {
    internal_state: Rc<RefCell<WidgetState>>,
}

fn get_event() -> Event { return Event::KeyDown('x'); }

use std::cell::{Ref, RefMut};

impl Widget {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Widget {
            internal_state: Rc::new(
                RefCell::new(
                    WidgetState {
                        gadgets: vec![],
                        active_gadget: 0,
                    }))}
    }
    fn state(&self) -> Ref<WidgetState> {
        self.internal_state.borrow()
    }
    fn state_mut(&self) -> RefMut<WidgetState> {
        self.internal_state.borrow_mut()
    }
    pub fn add_gadget(&self, gadget: Rc<dyn Gadget>) {
        self.state_mut().gadgets.push(gadget);
    }
    pub fn event_loop(&self) {
        for _ in 0..2 {
            {
                let event = get_event();
                let i_active = self.state().active_gadget;
                let active = self.state().gadgets[i_active].clone();
                active.handle_event(event, self);
            }
            // if need_repaint
            {
                let state = self.state();
                for i in 0..state.gadgets.len() {
                    let _ = state.gadgets[i].paint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    pub fn modal(&self) {
        let save_active;
        {
            let mut state = self.state_mut();
            save_active = state.active_gadget;
            let idx_gadgets = state.gadgets.len() - 1;
            state.active_gadget = idx_gadgets;
        }
        self.add_gadget(Rc::new(YGadget::new()));
        self.event_loop();
        let mut state = self.state_mut();
        state.active_gadget = save_active;
        state.gadgets.pop();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let widget = Widget::new();
    widget.add_gadget(Rc::new(XGadget {}));
    widget.event_loop();
}
```

Part of the beauty of the solution above is the structs that implement this pattern become a sort of "smart pointer" themselves and you can share the structs in many different parts of the code simply by cloning them. They don't need to be wrapped in smart pointers to be shared.